# Expected value of dice problem

Tags: probability

I had a question where you roll a fair dice. If you roll 2,3,4,5 you get 1$ if you roll a 6 you double all previous winnings and if you roll a 1 you lose all previous winnings.

For example if you rol 2,3,1,4,5,4,6 you would make 6$

whats the expected value.

Comment: When do you stop rolling the die?

Comment: @GrahamKemp:  I think the intent is you roll as long as you want.  If you quit you get the current score, but if you roll $1$ you must stop and get $0$.  OP should confirm.

Comment: it was expected value as after n=infinity rolls, which is why i was confused

Comment: Then the problem is not well posed.  There is no limit of the value as you go to infinity because you hit $0$ one time in six and many other times have positive value.  Report failure and say that and you are done.

Comment: yeah, I was a little shook getting a question like this on a final, but it was worded exactly like this, so hopefully the prof sees an error in the question. thanks anyways

Comment: If we preset a number of rolls, $n$, at which to end and multiply the bankroll by $r$ instead of $2$ when we roll a six, where $1\le r\lt2$, then I get the expected value, as $n\to\infty$, of $\frac4{2-r}$. As $r\to2$, we see that the expected value tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Maybe the question is asking for $\lim_{t \to \infty} E(X_t)$, where $X_t$ is the holding at time $t$.  (I agree that the question is ill-posed, whatever its intent.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doubling the existing payout at each $\unicode{x2685}$, multiply it by $r$, where $1\le r\lt2$.

Suppose we decide to stop at $N$ rolls, where $N$ tends to $\infty$. Then the probability that the last $\unicode{x2680}$ appeared on roll $N-n$ is
$$
\frac16\left(\frac56\right)^n\frac1{1-\left(\frac56\right)^N}\to\frac16\left(\frac56\right)^n\tag{1}
$$
Let's assume that the last $\unicode{x2680}$ appeared on roll $N-n$.

The probability that in those last $n$, non-$\unicode{x2680}$ rolls, we get $m\ \unicode{x2685}$s is
$$
\binom{n}{m}\left(\frac45\right)^{n-m}\left(\frac15\right)^m\tag{2}
$$
Let's assume that in the last $n$ rolls, we get $m\ \unicode{x2685}$s.

Consider the expected payouts of the remaining, non-$\unicode{x2685}$, dice with respect to their positions among the $\unicode{x2685}$s. The non-$\unicode{x2685}$ die with $k$ subsequent non-$\unicode{x2685}$s would be worth
$$
\frac1{\binom{n}{m}}\sum_{j=0}^mr^j\overbrace{\binom{k+j}{k}}^{\substack{\text{arrangements of}\\\text{subsequent dice}}}\overbrace{\binom{n-k-j-1}{n-k-m-1}}^{\substack{\text{arrangements of}\\\text{preceeding dice}}}\tag{3}
$$
where $j$ represents the number of subsequent $\unicode{x2685}$s.

Adding $(3)$ for each of the $n-m$ non-$\unicode{x2685}$ dice gives the expected sum
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\binom{n}{m}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-m-1}\sum_{j=0}^mr^j\binom{k+j}{k}\binom{n-k-j-1}{n-k-m-1}
&=\frac1{\binom{n}{m}}\sum_{j=0}^mr^j\binom{n}{m+1}\\
&=\frac1{\binom{n}{m}}\frac{r^{m+1}-1}{r-1}\binom{n}{m+1}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Accounting for $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get the expected payout to be
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac1{1-\left(\frac56\right)^N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac16\left(\frac56\right)^n\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}{m}\left(\frac45\right)^{n-m}\left(\frac15\right)^m\frac1{\binom{n}{m}}\frac{r^{m+1}-1}{r-1}\binom{n}{m+1}\\
&=\frac1{1-\left(\frac56\right)^N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left(\frac23\right)^{n+1}\sum_{m=0}^n\left(\frac14\right)^{m+1}\frac{r^{m+1}-1}{r-1}\binom{n}{m+1}\\
&=\frac1{r-1}\frac1{1-\left(\frac56\right)^N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left(\frac23\right)^{n+1}\left[\left(\frac{r+4}4\right)^n-\left(\frac54\right)^n\right]\\
&=\frac1{r-1}\frac4{1-\left(\frac56\right)^N}\left[\frac{1-\left(1-\frac{2-r}{6}\right)^N}{2-r}-1+\left(\frac56\right)^N\right]\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
For a finite $N$, the limit of $(5)$ as $r\to2$ is
$$
\frac23\frac{N}{1-\left(\frac56\right)^N}-4\tag{6}
$$
or for $1\le r\lt2$, the limit of $(5)$ as $N\to\infty$ is
$$
\frac4{2-r}\tag{7}
$$
In either case, as $r\to2$ and $N\to\infty$, the expected payout is $\infty$.

Comment: +1. Nice answer. Why didn't you get negative values ?. I was doing some simulations and I got positive and negative values for the expected payout.

Comment: @FelixMarin: How can we get negative values? $\unicode{x2680}$ resets the payout to $0$. $\unicode{x2685}$ doubles the payout. Everything else adds $\$1$ to the payout.

Comment: I got it. I didn't do the 'zero reset'. I subtract to the actual payout such that the player owes money to 'someone'. I'll change my simulation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Independent of your current winnings 1/6 to double it vs. 1/6 to lose it cancel each other out and provide a net 0 EV.

You're then left with just 4/6 chance for +1 so the total EV would just be 4/6*1 = $0.666

Comment: This is the EV for each roll, not for the whole game.

Comment: that is for each independant roll but, as you roll infinity times wouldnt your mean change?

Comment: @RossMillikan would the game's EV not simply be $0.66 * number of rolls you're permitted? if unlimited then the game should provide unlimited EV.

Comment: Usually I have seen this type of question posed with the criterion that you stop when you want and take the current score or the first time you roll $1$ and get nothing.  Yes, if there is a fixed number of rolls the EV would be $\frac 23$ per roll.  The paradox comes because (in my stopping rule) it seems you should keep rolling forever, but then the chance you get nothing is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you get to play until you decide to quit or until you roll a $1$ when you must quit with nothing.  This is a version of the [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox). Each roll has a positive EV of $\frac 23$, because if you have $d$ now you have $1/6$ chance of $0, 2/3$ chance of $d+1$ and $1/6$ chance of $2d$ so you should roll forever, but if you do it is certain you will roll a $1$ and get nothing.  You can read the Wikipedia article about various proposed resolutions to the paradox.

Added:  If there is no limit to the number of rolls, there is no limit to the expected value.  This would be true even without the doubling on $6$.  A badly posed question due to the lack of a stopping criterion.

Comment: In the question, the example $2,3,1,4,5,4,6$ is given and the payout is $\$6$. This indicates that a $1$ does not stop the game. Of course, it never says what does.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
\ds{pO_{n}:} & \mbox{Payout at step}\ \ds{n}.
\\[1mm]
\ds{R_{n}:} & \mbox{Roll at step}\ \ds{n}.
\\[1mm]
\ds{r:} & \mbox{A factor}\ \ds{\geq 1}.
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm]
pO_{0} & = 0
\\
pO_{n} &= \bracks{R_{n} \not= 1}\braces{\vphantom{\Large A}%
\bracks{2 \leq R_{n} \leq 5}\pars{pO_{n - 1} + 1} +
\bracks{R_{n} = 6}\pars{r\,pO_{n - 1}}}\,,\qquad n \geq 1
\end{align}

---

The figure shows a $\ds{\pars{~pO_{n}\ \mbox{vs.}\ n~}}$-simulation with $\ds{r = 1.5}$. According to the
[$@robjohn\ fine$ answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2260925/85343),
$\ds{pO_{n} \to 8}$ as $\ds{n \to \infty}$. The $\ds{\color{#f00}{red}}$ dots are the  $@robjohn$ result.

[image]